# Enable global navigation - MySites SP13

Tags: 2013, master-page, navigation, global-navigation

I'm looking to be able to show global navigation within our MySite host, and seemingly the only thing prohibiting this, is the master page *MySite15*. Obviously we could use the *Seattle* master page, giving us access to Global Navigation, however, we're pretty set upon using the *MySite15* template.

My question therefore, is; **What changes do I need to make to the master page file for Global Navigation to show?**

Would appreciate any pointers, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this. The reason being that MySite's are actually two SETS of site collections. The "My" site collection holds everything that isn't personalised. It still works if you don't allow personal MySites.

All of the personal sites are collections in their own rights but ones over which you have little or no control. You have no control over their templates for example, they are all created the way Microsoft wants them not how you want them!

So you can do what you want to the non-personalised part very easily but it is then extremely confusing to users because they go in and out of that - as they do, their menus and formatting will change. I did try this with our tenancy but I soon went back to the standard layout even though it is different to all of our other sites.

I would see about using the Managed Metadata Navigation feature in SharePoint 2013. It might require a custom server control or web part to accomplish but that would be about the only way I can think of to make them all the same without manually maintaining them on an individual basis.

You might be able to accomplish the separate sites with "pinning" or "reusing" term sets along with the managed navigation feature.

Comment: No change unfortunately

Comment: Is your publishing feature enable in your SharePoint site?

Comment: Yes it is. Note that the global nav shows on the "Site Settings" page, but not on the mysite host (http://mysites.local/default.aspx) page

Comment: Sorry mate but i need to change my answer

Comment: I don't agree. As I mentioned in my question, it is only the master page causing the difference. I can use the "Seattle" master page and the Top Navigation appears fine

Comment: Yes But I found same on few blogs. Please update here when you find the solution. I am also trying my best to help you.. Thanks..:)